# Send big object Array to spring boot controller and save data in the database

Tags: json, spring-boot, object

i have this following huge object from angular 7. so i need to post this object to spring boot app, which means from spring boot controller i need to save these data into the database. how should i do this? I have no idea at all. please help me

```
periodrw = [
    [
      {keyvalue:1, period: 1, day: null , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:2, period: 1, day: "Monday" , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:3, period: 1, day: "Tuesday" , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:4, period: 1, day: "Wednesday" , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:5, period: 1, day: "Thursday", subject :null },
      {keyvalue:6, period: 1, day: "Friday" , subject :null},
    ],
    [
      {keyvalue:1, period: 2, day: null , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:2, period: 2, day: "Monday" , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:3, period: 2, day: "Tuesday" , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:4, period: 2, day: "Wednesday" , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:5, period: 2, day: "Thursday" , subject :null},
      {keyvalue:6, period: 2, day: "Friday" , subject :null},
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the data as JSON form Angular and build a representing java class with the percistence annotation from javax.persistence . Deseriealize the JSON and map it to the class and at the end use the CrudRepository to save it.

here a hole tutorial: https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-crud-rest-service-with-jpa-hibernate